# UIWebView scrolls jerkily

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I need to use a website with quite a bit of content in my App via `UIWebView`.

When I scroll the page in Mobile Safari everything scrolls smoothly. Even if I scroll fast - the grey squared background appears but is rendered properly after a few moments (less then 0.5 seconds).

The same page in `UIWebView` scrolls jerkily if scrolled fast and doesn't show the grey squared background.
I guess Mobile Safari shows the grey squared background first and renders after that while `UIWebview` stops the scrolling until the part which will be shown is rendered.

How to I tell `UIWebView` to behave like Mobile Safari?

Answer (score 3):

It is already being drawn on it's own custom tiledLayer.  The problem is that it is by default attempting to draw itself on the main thread so it locks up when I can't be drawn.  There is a private message you can call

`-(void)_setDrawInWebThread:(BOOL)arg1`

That will work *BUT* you will see empty space when you scroll too fast and it can't keep up with the drawing until it has time to catch up.  They use:

`-(void)_setDrawsCheckededPattern:(BOOL)arg1`

in mobile safari to help with this.

Comment: Works great - but will get you rejected?

Comment: will apple reject your app if i user above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better solution. CGTiledLayer. 
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html