# How to get fast, smooth scrolling with UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiwebview, scroll

UIWebView exhibits jerky behavior when scrolling fast through lots of content. Mobile Safari, on the other hand, scrolls quickly and smoothly. It displays a simple checkerboard pattern while scrolling and then renders the page when scrolling is done.

How can we get Mobile Safari's fast, smooth scrolling behavior with a UIWebView?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I am in the same boat.

Comment: it doesn't look like any of the solutions on stackoverflow actually work. It would be hacky, but you could put a webview in a UITableView cell and resize the webview/cell to fit the page height, thus emulating the scroll speed of native tables

Answer (score -2):

Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187168/uiwebview-scrolls-jerkily) help?

> Found a better solution. CGTiledLayer.